# mysql_query connection NULL result, but I've connection successfully

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, connection, mysql-connect

I've problem with mysql. I've PHP script, which returned array into json data from datebase.
I've message from 'echo' about successfully connection, but my result is equals which null of array.

In result on Explorer I've:

```
Connected successfully

query: SELECT name,id FROM rz_DWzZ'

result: 

RESULT:[]
```

This is this script.

```
$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        mysql_select_db($database);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
$return_arr = array();
$qstring = "SELECT name,id FROM rz_DWzZ";
$result = mysql_query($qstring,$conn);
echo "<br>query: ".$qstring."<br>";
echo "<br>result: ".$result."<br>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))//loop through the retrieved values
{
        $row['name']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['name']));
        $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
        array_push($return_arr,$row);
}
mysql_close($conn); 
echo "<br>RESULT:".json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: So there are no rows in `rz_DWzZ`.

Comment: No. In table rz_DWzZ are rows. When I copy query from Explorer in my phpMyAdmin I've result.

Comment: If you `var_dump($result)` what do you get?

Comment: And why does your output seem to show a `'` at the end of the table name?

Comment: use `mysql_num_rows()` to check weather your query return result or not!!

Comment: var_dum($result) is returned: bool(false)

Comment: Then your query is failing. Have a look at [mysql_error](http://php.net/mysql_error) to find out what the issue is. I suspect it may have something to do with that quote.

Comment: ' in end of the table name is my fault when I scribe this question.
Saty: mysql_num_rows() is empty

Comment: Are you mixing mysqli with mysql at `$conn->connect_error`?

Comment: Ok. I've resolv. Jon - in mysql_error I've output "Table 'uslugi.rz_DWzZ' doesn't exist. 'uslugi' is my datebase.

Comment: and how does ur SQL Looks now ?

Comment: If this is resolved, please select (or add) an answer below and click the adjacent tick mark to set it as solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't check for failure properly. mysql_*() functions return boolean FALSE on failure, which `echo` will print as a zero-length/invisible string.

You have to explicitly test for it:

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--method #1

if ($result === false) { // method #2
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

And of course, you should NOT be using those functions anyways. They're obsolete/deprecated, and your code is now useless in newer versions of PHP. You should be using mysqli or PDO for any new development.

As well, you have numerous other bugs:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
```

the mysql_*() function library has NEVER been object-oriented. It's purely procedural, and has absolutely NO object support whatsoever. Therefore this connection test will always fail, as `$conn->connect_error` will always evaluate to null, which converts to boolean false as well, meaning you get a false positive for success.